# Compiling error with Android Phonegap app

Tags: android, cordova, barcode-scanner

I'm using Phonegap and Barcode Scanner plugin. I'm trying to build an test application. I'm following below tutorial.

http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials/tmt3

I have paste the BarcodeScanner.java to the correct path, as you see in the image.

But when compiling following error happens:

```
Android Packager: [phonegapbarcode] C:\Users\achintha_s\IdeaProjects\Barcode PhoneGap\AndroidManifest.xml:59: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/share_name').
```

How can I solve this? I'm using IntelliJ Studio.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `strings.xml` in `values` folder of `res` folder whether there is a string with name `share_name` as below:

```
<string name="share_name">My App Name</string>
```

and the `strings.xml` file should like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="share_name">My app Name</string>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sur you've a stringname `share_name` in your `String.xml` file.

```
<string name="share_name">My App</string>
```